# Reified inline function in Kotlin still leading to compiler error on 'is' check

Tags: kotlin, generics, kotlin-reified-type-parameters

I have the following function:

```
inline fun <reified T> create(preference: Preference<T>, title: String = ""): DebugOption{
        val type = when (preference) {
            is Preference<String> -> Type.STRING
            is Preference<Boolean> -> Type.BOOLEAN
            else -> Type.STRING
        }

        return DebugOption(type, preference, displayTitle = StringModel(title))
    }
```

I was expecting to be able to easily perform this 'is' check, since the generic type is reified, but I am still getting a compiler error:

```
Cannot check for instance of erased type: Preference<String>
Cannot check for instance of erased type: Preference<Boolean>
```

So I am confused how am I misusing 'reified' / what am I missing here.
Is there a problem with using reified generic types as the type parameter of another class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `is` checks the *runtime type* of `preference`, and the runtime type of `preference` isn't available until all the generic type information has been erased. [Reified types are not magic, after all.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70352154/why-to-use-inline-when-using-a-reified-type/70352259#70352259)

What you can do instead, is check `T` instead, since as you said, `T` is indeed reified.

```
val type = when (T::class) {
    String::class -> Type.STRING
    Boolean::class -> Type.BOOLEAN
    else -> Type.STRING
}
```

But note that if `Preference` is covariant (like `List`) or contravariant,  this might not work as you expect in some cases. For example:

```
// suppose Preference is covariant 
// (i.e. the type parameter is declared <out T>)
val pref: Preference<Any> = Preference<Boolean>()
create(pref, "foo")
```

In this case, `T` is inferred to be `Any`, so `type` will be assigned `Type.STRING`. If that is unexpected to you, and you want `Type.BOOLEAN` instead, you might want to use another way to check a preference's type, rather than reified types, as this cannot be determined at compile time.

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks!