# Cannot use 'T' as reified type parameter even I declared that T should be any class inherited by Parcelable

Tags: kotlin, generics, kotlin-reified-type-parameters, kotlin-inline-class

Since I am not yet good in generics I would like to ask:

**Question**: why I cannot inform the function `getResult` that the return value from `bundle.getParcelableCompat<T>(BUNDLE_KEY)` would be type of `T` (which is any class inheriting by Parcelable)?

I get error:

```
Cannot use 'T' as reified type parameter. Use a class instead.
```

What am I mising? I though I passed all needed information what I am trying to achieve.

```
class MyClass<T : Parcelable>(
    private val key: String,
    private val clazz: Class<T>
) {

    private inline fun <reified T : Parcelable> Bundle.getParcelableCompat(name: String): T? =
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 33) {
            this.getParcelable(name, T::class.java)
        } else {
            this.getParcelable(name)
        }
    
    fun getResult(fragment: Fragment, result: (T) -> Unit) = with(fragment) {
        setFragmentResultListener(requestKey) { request, bundle ->
            if (request == requestKey) {
                val parcelableCompat: T? = bundle.getParcelableCompat<T>(BUNDLE_KEY)
                parcelableCompat?.let(result)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70352154/why-to-use-inline-when-using-a-reified-type/70352259#70352259), reified type parameters in Kotlin are not magic. The compiler still needs a runtime-available type at the call site, so that it can inline your `getParcelableCompat` method.

To see how this does not work, just inline it yourself:

```
fun getResult(fragment: Fragment, result: (T) -> Unit) = with(fragment) {
    setFragmentResultListener(requestKey) { request, bundle ->
        if (request == requestKey) {
            val parcelableCompat: T? = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 33) {
                this.getParcelable(BUNDLE_KEY, T::class.java)
            } else {
                this.getParcelable(BUNDLE_KEY)
            }
            parcelableCompat?.let(result)
        }
    }
}
```

See how there is `T::class.java`? You are trying to get the class of a non-reified type parameter, which is not allowed.

In cases where you call `getParcelableCompat` with a non-type-parameter class, the inlining would come out fine. The `T` in `T::class.java` would be replaced with that class you used.

Since the class type parameter `T` cannot be reified, there is really no point in making `getParcelableCompat` have a reified type parameter. It can accept a `Class<T>` instead:

```
class MyClass<T : Parcelable>(
    private val key: String,
    private val clazz: Class<T>
) {

    private fun <T : Parcelable> Bundle.getParcelableCompat(name: String, clazz: Class<T>): T? =
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 33) {
            this.getParcelable(name, clazz)
        } else {
            this.getParcelable(name)
        }
    
    fun getResult(fragment: Fragment, result: (T) -> Unit) = with(fragment) {
        setFragmentResultListener(requestKey) { request, bundle ->
            if (request == requestKey) {
                val parcelableCompat: T? = bundle.getParcelableCompat(BUNDLE_KEY, clazz)
                parcelableCompat?.let(result)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Alternatively, don't make `getParcelableCompat` generic at all, since you can use the type parameter `T` from `MyClass`

```
class MyClass<T : Parcelable>(
    private val key: String,
    private val clazz: Class<T>
) {

    private fun Bundle.getParcelableCompat(name: String): T? =
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 33) {
            this.getParcelable(name, clazz)
        } else {
            this.getParcelable(name)
        }
    
    fun getResult(fragment: Fragment, result: (T) -> Unit) = with(fragment) {
        setFragmentResultListener(requestKey) { request, bundle ->
            if (request == requestKey) {
                val parcelableCompat: T? = bundle.getParcelableCompat(BUNDLE_KEY)
                parcelableCompat?.let(result)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

when you call `bundle.getParcelableCompat<T>(BUNDLE_KEY)` inside `getResult` `T` (the one delcared by MyClass) has already been erased so the reified parameter does not help you. It's helpful (and mostly correct!) to think about a reified parameter as just saving you the extra argument of `T::class`, instead the compiler passes it for you.

However you already keep a `Class<T>` around, there's no need for the extra complexity. The following should work.

```kotlin
class MyClass<T : Parcelable>(
    private val key: String,
    private val clazz: Class<T>
) {

    private inline fun Bundle.getParcelableCompat(name: String): T? =
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 33) {
            this.getParcelable(name, clazz)
        } else {
            this.getParcelable(name)
        }
    
    fun getResult(fragment: Fragment, result: (T) -> Unit) = with(fragment) {
        setFragmentResultListener(requestKey) { request, bundle ->
            if (request == requestKey) {
                val parcelableCompat: T? = bundle.getParcelableCompat(BUNDLE_KEY)
                parcelableCompat?.let(result)
            }
        }
    }
}
```